# workbox-google-analytics : Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'sync' in undefined

Tags: google-analytics, workbox

Issue opened [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2392)

Library Affected:
workbox-google-analytics

Browser & Platform:
Chrome Version 80.0.3987.122

Issue or Feature Request Description:

I've added the plugin with the following configuration in my index.js:

```
import * as googleAnalytics from 'workbox-google-analytics';

googleAnalytics.initialize({
  parameterOverrides: {
    cd1: 'offline'
  },
  hitFilter: params => {
    const queueTimeInSeconds = Math.round(params.get('qt') / 1000);
    params.set('cm1', queueTimeInSeconds);
  }
});
```

It generates the following error in console :

```
Queue.js:289 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'sync' in undefined
    at Queue._addSyncListener (Queue.js:289)
    at new Queue (Queue.js:59)
    at new BackgroundSyncPlugin (BackgroundSyncPlugin.js:33)
    at Module.initialize (initialize.js:166)
    at Object../app/index.jsx (index.jsx:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:725)
    at fn (bootstrap:100)
    at Object.0 (index.js:68)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:725)
    at bootstrap:792
```

I'm trying to setup the plugin with gtag (despite [#2389](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/workbox/issues/2389)), here is the init in index.html

```
<script
      async
      src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxxx-1"
    ></script>
    <script>
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag() {
        dataLayer.push(arguments);
      }
      gtag('js', new Date());

      gtag('config', 'UA-xxxx-1');

      gtag('set', 'dimension1', 'online');
</script>
```

On Analytics, I have 1 personalized dimension `dimension1` for Network Status and 1 metric `metric1` for Offline Queue Time

Answer (score 0):

Issue is closed.

```
The googleAnalytics.initialize()
```

code must be added inside service worker script and not in main index.js